# Picasso loading already created bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I am trying to get Picasso to load a bitmap.

When I try to use `Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(bitmap1).into(image);` it gives me the error `he method load(Uri) in the type Picasso is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap)`.

How would I be able to make it so that Picasso loads my bitmap? thanks.

Comment: You don't need Picasso for this.... Picasso is to load images from the internet. Just use `image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Comment: @Nadeem Iqbal It's a bitmap.

Comment: @Jack! From where you are getting the bitmap? From internet or local file or Drawable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need Picasso to do this. Picasso is for loading images from the internet or from the disk. You can display a `Bitmap` in your `ImageView` like this:

```
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: The reason I am using Picasso because it handles the images really well, when I just use "image.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));" it lags horribly.

Comment: @Jack then you are doing something horribly wrong. It should never lag if  you do this, even if the images were huge. Try the suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Loading local resources is also possible, as you can see here: http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
RESOURCE LOADING
Resources, assets, files, content providers are all supported as image sources.

Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView2);
```

Bu you shouldn't try to create the Bitmap. I think the reason for lagging is the actual bitmap creation.